# More problems with ViewPager example

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I downloaded a ViewPager example from GitLib and, unfortunately, it had a "Sherlock theme" packaged with it that got all sorts of errors.  I was advised, on another post to remove the theme, one step of that was to change the code below to extend from FragmentActivity instead of SherlockFragmentActivity.  But when I do that I get errors. 
setContentView(R.layout.main) errors saying that 'main' is not a field
the R.id.pager errors saying 'pager' is not a field
Since I don't understand how this code works yet, I don't know how to fix the errors.
Any insight would be appreciated.
thanks, Gary

```
public class ViewPagerFragmentDemoActivity extends    SherlockFragmentActivity {  
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
  setContentView(R.layout.main);    
  ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);    
  pager.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));  
 }
}
```

Comment: Link to the example would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your R.java file has not been rebuilt (or you are pointing to the wrong one now).

Look in your imports for an android R file (IIRC it is com.android.R)... if it is there delete it.  Then clean your project and Eclipse should then rebuild yours and import it.

Another possibility is that you have an error in an xml file. If the compiler cannot parse the xml file,  it will fail to generate a new R.java file. Usually there is a little red flag on the problematic child.

Comment: I removed the import Android.R and that did it.  Thanks.

Comment: Great.  Please accept this answer then (click the check.mark next to it).  That way people will know it is resolved.  You should do that for any question you ask for the reason I gave above as well as giving credit to the person that helped.you.